# Adding video in Allure Report using Allure jenkins plugin

Tags: protractor, jenkins-plugins, allure

I was trying various ways to embed a test run video in Allure Report plugin with Protractor.
we can do it if we add a video Folder inside the Allure Report folder and add the video path in the allure description . So then Allure displays and play the video in description part.

However, i wanted to achieve the same using the Allure Jenkins plugin. Can you please let me know if there is any way to embed and play the video in allure report generated using allure jenkins plugin.

I saw the Video on you tube where they are running video inside the Allure report in jenkins. But not sure how they have setup. Please help?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74zD5q9DKTw

Comment: Hi, did you maybe find solution? If yes can you explain how did you manage this?

Answer (score 0):

seems has no business of "jenkins plugin",  you could rewrite the testngListener , and add the vedios with "Attachement"

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    super.onTestFailure(result);


    String mp4 = store + "\\" + sessionId + ".mp4";
    File file = new File(mp4);
    if (file.exists()) {
        attachRecord(mp4);
    }

}


@Attachment(value = "record screen", type = "video/mp4")
private byte[] attachRecord(String mp4) {

    System.out.println("mp4 -->" + mp4);
    Path content = Paths.get(mp4);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = Files.newInputStream(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return is2ByeteArray(is);
}


public static byte[] is2ByeteArray(InputStream is) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buff = new byte[100];
    int rc = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (!((rc = is.read(buff, 0, 100)) > 0)) break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        baos.write(buff, 0, rc);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```